# Find if one map is subset of another

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have two STL maps `std::map<int, int> foo = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}};` and `std::map<int, int> bar = {{2, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}};`

I want to find if bar is a subset of foo.

Since the elements are sorted in map, I would think
to find the first element from bar in foo, and then find consecutive elements 
from bar in foo from that location.

The problem here is I'm not able to figure out a way to do that with STL maps in cpp.
Can I reduce the search range in map for every find from a location in map to the end of the map?

I hope I explained the problem.

Comment: If those are maps, are you listing the keys? Or the value types? Or are they sets?

Comment: your map looks like set

Comment: Sorry for confusion. These are keys, map is "map<int,SomeInfo*>". I am interested in finding if second map has keys subset of keys in first map.

Comment: @H2CO3 - I've given up on that one. Apparently "STL" now stands for STandard Library.

Comment: @PeteBecker Perhaps I will give up one day too (but not yet!)

Comment: @H2CO3: absurd nitpicking... STL is a well known term, and it is not incorrectly used here. It is not like he was calling `std::iostream` STL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`std::includes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) algorithm with a custom comparator that compares only the keys:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> foo = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}};
    std::map<int, int> bar = {{2, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}};
    typedef std::pair<int,int> pair;

    std::cout <<
       std::includes(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end(),
           [](const pair& p1, const pair& p2)
           {
               return p1.first < p2.first;
           });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could extract key sets (`set1` and `set2`) of both maps (`foo` and `bar`), and as long as they are sorted, you can do the following:

```
if (std::includes(set1.begin(), set1.end(),
                  set2.begin(), set2.end())) {
  // ...
}
```

See [`std::includes`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/includes/).

Comment: Why extract the keys? You can do it on the fly, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) in combination with [`boost::includes`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/set/includes.html):

```
using namespace boost::adaptors;
bool result = includes(foo | map_keys, bar | map_keys);
```

Here is how a minimal, complete program could look like (mapped values are disregarded):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> foo = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}};
    std::map<int, int> bar = {{2, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}};

    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    std::cout << includes(foo | map_keys, bar | map_keys);
}
```

Here is a [***live example***](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24443).