# Check if map contains all the keys from another map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

[Check if map in C++ contains all the keys from another map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775028/check-if-map-in-c-contains-all-the-keys-from-another-map) answers my question but I'm not sure how we iterate through two maps at the same time.

I know how to iterate through one as shown:

```
typedef std::map<QString, PropertyData> TagData;
TagData original = readFileToMap("FoxHud.bak");

for (TagData::const_iterator tagIterator = original.begin(); tagIterator != original.end(); tagIterator++) {
}
```

Comment: Use a while loop and two iterator variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find if one map is subset of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045108/find-if-one-map-is-subset-of-another)

Comment: I'd say 12775028 is a duplicate of 16045108. But this question is more about how to iterate through 2 maps in the general sense (we need to make sense of this question, in comparison to the one referenced which was already answered correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate the 2 maps simultaneously, you can do this:

```
if (map1.size() != map2.size())
  ; // problem
else
{
  for (map<X,Y>::const_iterator it1 = map1.begin(),
                                it2 = map2.begin();
       it1 != map1.end() && it2 != map2.end();
       ++it1 , ++it2)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now if you want to iterate through the 2 maps at different "speeds", then a while loop to condition the increments of it1 and it2 independently would then be more appropriate. See [Golgauth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17255086/1677690) for an example.

Comment: But the algorithm should work for maps with different sizes from each other !

Comment: This doesn't work that way ether, read again the prerequisites : stackoverflow.com/q/12775028/1715716 = `I want to verify that the intersection of the set of keys of m1 and m2 is the same as the set of keys of m2`. The OP didn't ask for checking if the two maps are identical... Moreover this code doesn't compile: `tagIterator.first` should be `tagIterator->first`.

Comment: "I'm not sure how we iterate through two maps at the same time." Was the question. It's a request for clarification of the original. A solution that shows how to "iterate through two maps" doesn't have to solve the problem presented in stackoverflow.com/q/12775028/1715716

Comment: Indeed, let's focus on answering the current question, the other one was answered already. However it's true that being able to iterate through the 2 maps at different speeds should be part of the answer here. I edited my answering and now point to Golgauth's one for completion.

Comment: @JonL Sure but we also had to focus on the complementary question induced by the title of the question : "Check if map contains all the keys from another map". So to my eyes, this was fully part of the question... Isn't it ? Well, no need to fight on this: both answers are complementary.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
// As std::map keys are sorted, we can do:

typedef std::map<string, int> TagData;
TagData map1;
TagData map2;
...
TagData::const_iterator map1It = map1.begin();
TagData::const_iterator map2It = map2.begin();

bool ok = true;
std::size_t cnt = 0;

while (map2It != map2.end() && map1It != map1.end()) {
    if (map1It->first != map2It->first) {
        map1It++;
    } else {
        map2It++;
        cnt++;
    }
}

if (cnt != map2.size()) ok = false;

cout << "OK = " << ok << endl;
```

This should work with maps that are not the same size, as well.